# Select COUNT(*) in MSSQL without FROM

Tags: sql-server

Why does it output 1?

```
select count(*)
```

Why will this work?

```
SELECT 'penguins'
WHERE 1 = 2
HAVING 0 < 1;
```

Why doesn't it work? I mean, why doesn't it give out a 1 similarly to "penguins"?

```
select count(*)
WHERE 1 = 2
HAVING 0 < 1;
```

I don't understand how this works. Can someone explain?

Comment: HAVING count(*)<1.   Just an aside 1 will NEVER equal 2

Comment: There are two group bys in sql server, a scalar and another which i don't remember the name for. One of them always returns a row. If you add group by, the stuff dissapears

Comment: @siggemannen - scalar vs vector. So the `HAVING` makes the penguins query a scalar aggregate

Comment: *"Why doesn't it work?"* That 3rd query works fine for me; what error are you getting?

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you, that's the name. From what I remember of my experiments, any kind of aggregate operators without a `group by` becomes scalar one.

Comment: The "Wihout FROM" isn't really relevant as same results https://dbfiddle.uk/ONjNjxfr

Comment: Thom A, I mean, why doesn't it give out a 1 similarly to "penguins"?

Comment: You should clarify that in the question, @virex-84 .

Comment: @MartinSmith Penguins... Fun visualization.  In my little head, I see squirrels gathering nuts.

Comment: Please don't add conflicting tags like that: [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: This is <sql-server> specific behavior. so I removed the ANSI/ISO <sql> tag - where all of the above queries have invalid syntax.

Comment: The only part that's a little unclear, to me at least, is how or why SQL Server is treating the having clause, seemingly without a group-by it must be taking precedence; comparing two execution plans, the plan with *having* has a <constantscan> element with a <row> and the string constant, whereas in the plan with only a *where* clause the <constantscan/> is empty.

Comment: Re #1, unlike ISO SQL, SQL Server allows one to omit the `FROM` clause which is functionality like selecting from a single-row virtual table. In some other DBMS products, it is necessary to specify a FROM clause, such as `FROM SYSDUMMY1` (DB2) or `FROM DUAL` (Oracle).

Answer (score 2):

It may help to look at several similar queries together.

```
SELECT 'a'              -- One row
SELECT 'b' WHERE 1 = 2  -- Zero rows

SELECT COUNT(*)              -- Result = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE 1 = 2  -- Result = 0

SELECT COUNT(*) HAVING 0 < 1              -- Result = 1 (passes having criteria)
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE 1 = 2 HAVING 0 < 1  -- Result = 0 (passes having criteria)

SELECT COUNT(*) HAVING 0 > 1              -- No results (fails having criteria)
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE 1 = 2 HAVING 0 > 1  -- No results (fails having criteria)

SELECT 'penguins' FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) A(I) -- Two rows containing fixed 'penguins' value
SELECT 'penguins' FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) A(I) HAVING 0 < 1 -- One aggregated row containing fixed 'penguins' value  (passes having criteria)
SELECT 'penguins' FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) A(I) HAVING 0 = 1 -- No results (fails having criteria)

SELECT 'penguins' WHERE 1 = 2 -- Zero rows
SELECT 'penguins' WHERE 1 = 2 HAVING 0 < 1 -- One aggregated row containing fixed value 'penguins'
SELECT 'penguins' WHERE 1 = 2 HAVING 0 = 1 -- No results (fails having criteria)
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MpGV0nCo).

A query with no `FROM` clause normally returns one row containing the selected values. Adding a `WHERE` clause may eliminate that one row.

If the select list contains `COUNT(*)`, the select statement now becomes an aggregation. Lacking a `GROUP BY` clause, *all* rows are aggregated into one (even if there are zero rows feeding the group-by). **This is properly known as a *scalar aggregate*.** If there was one row before the aggregation, the count will be `1`. If there were no rows feeding the aggregation, the count will be '0' but that count is still part of the result.

The `HAVING` clause then filters the aggregation results. If the condition is true, the aggregation result is retained in the final result. If the condition is false, the aggregation result is excluded.

As for the `SELECT 'penguins' WHERE 1 = 2 HAVING 1 < 0` case, the presence of the `HAVING` clause also triggers an aggregation (even without `GROUP BY`), but turns it into a [vector aggregate](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html) (which has slightly different semantics). The `'penguins'` value then just becomes a fixed value within the aggregated results. Since the `HAVING` criteria passes, that aggregated row is included in the final result.

All is working as designed.

Comment: Not 100% right. If there is no `GROUP BY` *or* `HAVING` then you get scalar aggregation, otherwise you get vector aggregation. Difference being that scalar aggregation always returns exactly one row. Eg see the results if you add `GROUP BY ()`

Comment: @Charlieface - Learned something new today. I expanded the answer above a bit, including pointing out the *scalar aggregate* terminology. I thing my thought process of "all (zero or more) rows into one" is consistent with the *scalar aggregate* behavior.

Answer (score -2):

This is best example

```sql
select count(*)
WHERE 1 = 2
HAVING 0 < 1;
```

Without `FROM`, it comes down to 1 row - `select count(*)`

```
select count(*) -- result: 1. You selected one row
```

Add `WHERE 1 = 2` - no rows returned because 1 <> 2. Hence result is 0.

Also, you can do `select count(1)`, or `select count(33)`, without `FROM`, there are no columns. It creates an output "count" column

Bottom line, this is just an engine behavior. **This must be some sort of new ANSI SQL standard** (about omitted `from` and present `where`), because Oracle 23c works but prior versions don't. MySQL 8.0 works but 5.5 don't. SQLite 3.39 works but 3.27 don't